# Converting Dictionary to Dataframe with tuple as key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary like this

```
df_dict = {(7, 'hello'): {1}, (1, 'fox'): {2}}
```

I want to transform it into a dataframe where the first part of the tuple is the row header, and the second part of the tuple is the column header.  I tried this:

```
doc_df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict, index=[df_dict.keys()[0]], columns = [df_dict.keys()[1]])
```

But I got the error `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing`

I want my dataframe to look like:

```
_ | fox  | hello  
1 | 2    | null  
7 | null | 1
```

How do I index into the keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `TypeError` is that `df_dict.keys()` is an iterator which yields keys from the `dict` one by one. The elements it yields will be `(7, 'hello')` and `(1, 'fox')`, but it doesn't "know" that in advance. The iterator itself doesn't have any idea how many elements it has or what sort of structure those elements might have, and in particular, it doesn't have any way to access an element by index number.

Now, you can use the `itertools.islice` function to access a given-numbered element from an iterable, but it involves throwing away everything that comes beforehand. So that's not what you want.

The answer to the question you're *asking*, which is how you index into the keys, is to convert them into a list first:

```
l = list(df_dict.keys())
```

and then you can use `l[0]` and `l[1]` and so on.

But even that isn't what you're actually going to need for your application. The resulting list, in your example, would be

```
[(7, 'hello'), (1, 'fox')]
```

so `l[0]` will be `(7, 'hello')` and `l[1]` will be `(1, 'fox')` (or vice-versa, since you don't know which order the keys will come out in). What you actually want to access is `(7, 1)` and `('hello', 'fox')`, for which you either need to use something like a list comprehension:

```
[x[0] for x in l] # (7, 1)
[x[1] for x in l] # ('hello', 'fox')
```

or you could convert it to a NumPy array and transpose that.

```
npl = numpy.array(l) # array([[7, 'hello'], [1, 'fox']])
nplT = npl.T         # array([[7, 1], ['hello', 'fox']])
```

Now you can use `nplT[0]` and so on.