# Tuple key Dictionary to Table/Graph 3-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, plot, graph

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {(100,22,123):'55%',(110,24,123):'58%'}
```

Where, for example, the elements of the tuple are (x,y,z) and the value is the error rate of something... I want to print that dictionary but I'm not very clear how to do it or in what format to do it (which would be better to see easily the information, maybe: x - y - z - Rate ).

I found that: [Converting Dictionary to Dataframe with tuple as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805689/converting-dictionary-to-dataframe-with-tuple-as-key) ,but I think it does not fit what I want and I can not understand it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you need dataframe? `df = pd.Series(d).reset_index()` ?

Comment: Oh yes this is perfect, now I only need to change the names of level_0, level_... and will be nice

Comment: `for k,v in dict.iteritems() :   print k, v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), last only set new column names:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {(100,22,123):'55%',(110,24,123):'58%'}
df = pd.Series(d).reset_index()
df.columns = ['a','b','c', 'd']
print (df)
     a   b    c    d
0  100  22  123  55%
1  110  24  123  58%
```